# How do I make my images scaleable and at the same time maintain their aspect ratio?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on my website and I've been designing on a samsung 22 inch monitor. I haven't been playing with resizing the window, just basically designing my site with the window at full screen. Now I made an image slider on my homepage and I noticed that the images in the slider scale down while maintaining aspect ratio when I resize the window but the images not in the slider which I created to fit appropriately in full screen mode remain the same size when i'm resizing the window so it messes up the layout. I haven't really done much with the css on the images except changing the margins but is there anything I can do with css to tell the images to scale the images when resizing window.

CSS code for my images

```
.project-section  img{
   display:inline;
   margin-top: -18px;
   margin-bottom: -5px;
   margin-left: -8px;
}
```

css code for my image slider I got from a tutorial which I'm still trying to understand but the images here do scale when resizing thed window.

```
          @keyframes slidy {
           0% { left: 0%; }
           20% { left: 0%; }
           25% { left: -100%; }
           45% { left: -100%; }
           50% { left: -200%; }
           70% { left: -200%; }
           75% { left: -300%; }
           95% { left: -300%; }
          100% { left: -400%; }
            }


  div#slider { overflow: hidden; }
  div#slider figure img { width: 20%; float: left; }
  div#slider figure { 
   position: relative;
   width: 500%;
   margin: 0;
   left: 0;
   text-align: left;
   font-size: 0;
   animation: 40s slidy infinite; 
 }
```

Comment: Is there anymore code? width: auto; might work too. It'll maintain aspect ratio at whatever the height of the slider etc.

Comment: Without specified dimensions, images will render at their own size. If you want them to scale according to available width, you should set them to display: block and 100% width.

Comment: just added the code for the image slider

Comment: right now the images I want to scale are contained in a div class called project-section. Do I just set the width of this div class to a 100% or set the images in the div class to a 100%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image scaling while preserving the ratio with CSS works by specifying one of width or height (depending on which one you know) and set the other one to `auto`. If your responsive design asks for images to be 480px wide, that would be:

```
width: 480px;
height: auto;
```